# Google sheets lookup with substring on range

Tags: google-sheets, range, substring, google-sheets-formula, lookup

I am trying to do substring lookups with Google Sheets.

**I am able to do it when the substring is applied on the lookup string:**

[image]

```
Match = VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",$C$2:$C,1,FALSE)
```

**However I'm stuck when it comes to applying the substring logic to the range:**

[image]

**Any idea how to achieve this?**

*Note: I've used simplistic values for the sake of the example, in reality the `search/range` values don't always follow the `[0-9][a-z][0-9] / [a-z]` pattern, so removing the digits from search then performing the search isn't the solution I'm looking for.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",1,QUERY(C$2:C$4,"select C where '"&A2&"' contains C"))
```

- QUERY to find the substring match
- TEXTJOIN to join matched substring,if more than one is found.

Comment: works as well, thanks for showing `QUERY/TEXTJOIN` use case, might be useful in the future

Answer (score 2):

Put the following formula in B2, which then needs to be copied down (alas, I did not find a method of applying ARRAYFORMULA to the second range in FILTER).

```
=filter(C$2:C$4, regexmatch(A2, C$2:C$4))
```

[image]

Comment: That works, found another solution (see my answer) to support regular expression in the range values.

Answer (score 1):

@ttarchala's answer works. If your range contains several matches but only want 1, wrap it with `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(C$2:C$4, regexmatch(A2, C$2:C$4)),1)
```

An alternative is to use the following, which allows for values in the range to be regular expressions:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,JOIN("|",C$2:C$4))
```

[image]

Eg see how `3c3` fails to match `c\b` because of the `\b` word boundary whereas `c` matches it.